# Why is Aptana Slow on Gnome 3 and Nvidia on Mageia 2?

Tags: aptana3

This is a problem I've had with an Nvidia GeForce 8400 GS video card, running Gnome 3 on Mageia 2 and using Aptana Studio 3.

Symptom: scrolling is unbearably slow - e.g. scrolling with the mouse wheel could take eight seconds to complete the scroll. Editing was also painful waiting for saves.

I know this is something to do with the Nvidia card as well as Aptana (see my solution) but has anyone else experienced this and have a better solution?

Best regards

Neill

Comment: Hello Neill, please post your answer as an answer (there's a checkbox in the question asking page for that), and your question in the form of an actual question (as if you had asked it prior to finding the solution). This is how this site operates. (You can edit your question with the "edit" link right under the tags.)

Comment: This also seems like it is a better fit for Super User, as it doesn't seem to deal with programming all that much.

Comment: @MikeC: well, it's a problem with the Aptana Studio IDE. Dev tool issues are on-topic here.

Comment: @Mat - sorry cannot find the answer button you're talking about. Checked by going through the ask question process and cannot see it anywhere.

Comment: @NeillJones: when you initially post a question, there's a checkbox right below the "post your question" button. Now since you've posted your "question" without checking that box, you might be restricted from posting an answer for ~48h (not sure this restriction still exists). If that still exists, wait a couple of days. If not, the answer box is right below ↓

Comment: @Mike - nothing to do with programming - I was following the aptana discussion topics to post the issue there - it seems to come through to this site so had no choice but to post it here. The issue is most obvious in Aptana so it's most likely that's what might drive someone to start looking for an answer. After searching for three days for an answer, I thought it right to save someone else the time.

Comment: @Mat - ok that might explain why I can't see it. (checked again and it's not there at the moment). Tried to answer with the answer button but cannot do so at the moment. Will try to remember to do it tomorrow.

Comment: @Mat - ok posted it back up as a question - hope it is ok now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

New Solution to supercede one suggested below.

The problem seems to be a combination of JDK, nvidia, and gnome 3 (at least on Mageia 2 - not sure about Ubuntu etc). The best solution I got in the end was to use the nouveau driver *without* 3D acceleration, and then it works ok again. (With 3D acceleration nouveau currently seems to hang after about 5 minutes but in the meantime it ran Aptana fine.)

Netbeans seemed to have other problems instead, and the problem was also present in Eclipse. On KDE Aptana ran perfectly (quicker than on gnome at the best of times). So that is why I think JDK plus nvidia plus gnome 3 were not playing nicely.

An alternative solution is to use KDE instead for the desktop.

Old solution:

Solution of a sort: assuming you're using the 295.xxx nvidia driver (and not nouveau), then in Mageia control center->hardware->set up the graphical server, under options, turn OFF "Enable RENDER acceleration" where it warns having it on could cause problems with text rendering. Doing this seems to speed up Aptana back to pre-nvidia speeds.

However, X will now use up a large amount of CPU as it compensates for the lack of Render Acceleration. SO this is more of a work-around.

I've tried this with the latest nvidia beta release driver and the problem still remains.

It seems to be a combination of Aptana may be doing too much processing while scrolling, redrawing etc, the nvidia drivers with the text bug and gnome 3 being a bit slower. For example netbeans doesn't seem to have the same issue.